# Download file asynchronously with AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to download asynchronously a file from server. 
My files are located in 'files' directory - one directory higher than the content of the website.

In my code I have an ajax click event on div witch run asynchronously a php file named 'get_file.php' with some variables (GET method).

This is content of 'get_file.php'

```
<?php

$dir    =   '../../files/'; 
$file   =   $_GET['file'];  

if (file_exists($dir . $file)) {

            // only for test run a file via ajax
            file_put_contents("test.tht", $dir . $file);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dir . $file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir . $file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($dir . $file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Code works corectly in part of transfer variables (because in test file.txt I can find a path and file name), but download doesn't start. 
What is wrong?

Comment: get_file.php content is missing.

Comment: Edited the post to fix code formatting problems

Comment: You don't use ajax for that, you just link to the file, and the header will make the file download instead of redirecting. When using ajax, nothing happens, as expected.

Comment: But I have two problems:
- I don't want to show my files loction,
- I have my files one directory higher then www directory

Comment: A rewrite rule would do that as well. However, if you want PHP, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle file download from ajax post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Comment: @Robin: That's close, but this is a simpler case: no `POST` is needed; a `GET` will work just fine, and that needs no trickery.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax will not help you here. Instead you can trigger your download by either set the src-attribute of an invisible iFrame or by navigating to the download URL.

// iFrame approach

```
<iframe  style="display:none" id="downloadFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

-

```
<script>
  var iframe = document.getElementById("downloadFrame");
  iframe.src = "get_file.php?file=testfile.txt";
</script>
```

// OR Navigate to the download url

```
window.location.href = "get_file.php?file=testfile.txt";
```

Apart from that you really should check your input in your get_file.php. Users will be able to download everything (../index.php) as long you do not check the incoming filename.